# How can I count the number of messages to different people per day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// messages
+----+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| id |    content     | sender_id | receiver_id |  date_time  |
+----+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1  | whatever1      | 1         | 3           | 1521097240  |
| 2  | whatever2      | 3         | 1           | 1521097241  |
| 3  | whatever3      | 1         | 3           | 1521097242  |
| 4  | whatever4      | 1         | 4           | 1521097243  |
| 5  | whatever5      | 1         | 5           | 1521097244  |
| 6  | whatever6      | 5         | 1           | 1521097245  |
+----+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now I need to count the number of messages that user `sender_id = 1` to different people. So assuming all those row are in the past day, then the result should be `3`. Because `sender_id = 1` have sent messages to `receiver_ids = 3,4,5`. How can I do that count in Mysql?

---

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT count(1) as sent_messages_num
FROM messages
WHERE sender_id = 1  
AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

So all I need it adding a grouping. But not sure how should I do that?

Comment: do you want the number of messages or the number of different receivers? because 1 sent a total of 4 messages (he sent two messages to receiver_id 3)

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: @jarlh The expected result is the number of `3`. Which will be achieved (as others said) by using `count(distinct receiver_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `distinct` in `COUNT`

```
SELECT count(distinct receiver_id) as sent_messages_num
FROM users
WHERE sender_id = 1  
AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as sent_messages_num, receiver_id
FROM users
WHERE sender_id = 1  
AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY receiver_id
```

This will give you the number of messages per receiver. After I read the answer again, I think the following might suit better:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT receiver_id) as sent_messages_num
FROM users
WHERE sender_id = 1  
AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```